# Do I really have to retype all the columns in a MERGE statement?

Tags: sql-server

Suppose I have a table `PRODUCTS` with many columns, and that I want to insert/update a row using a MERGE statement. It is something along these lines:

```
MERGE INTO PRODUCTS AS Target
USING (VALUES(42, 'Foo', 'Bar', 0, 14, 200, NULL)) AS Source (ID, Name, Description, IsSpecialPrice, CategoryID, Price, SomeOtherField)
ON Target.ID = Source.ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    -- update
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    -- insert
```

To write the UPDATE and INSERT "sub-statements" it seems I have to specify once again each and every column field. So `-- update` would be replaced by

```
UPDATE SET ID = Source.ID, Name = Source.Name, Description = Source.Description...
```

and `-- insert` by

```
INSERT (ID, Name, Description...) VALUES (Source.ID, Source.Name, Source.Description...)
```

This is very error-prone, hard to maintain, and apparently not really needed in the simple case where I just want to merge two "field sets" each representing a full table row. I appreciate that the update and insert statements could actually be anything (I've already used this in an unusual case in the past), but it would be great if there was a more concise way to represent the case where I just want "Target = Source" or "insert Source".

Does a better way to write the update and insert statements exist, or do I really need to specify the full column list every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write the complete column lists.

You can check the documentation for [`MERGE` here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#syntax). Most SQL Server statement documentation starts with a syntax definition that shows you *exactly* what is allowed. For instance, the section for `UPDATE` is defined as:

```
<merge_matched>::=  
    { UPDATE SET <set_clause> | DELETE }  

<set_clause>::=  
SET  
  { column_name = { expression | DEFAULT | NULL }  
  | { udt_column_name.{ { property_name = expression  
                        | field_name = expression }  
                        | method_name ( argument [ ,...n ] ) }  
    }  
  | column_name { .WRITE ( expression , @Offset , @Length ) }  
  | @variable = expression  
  | @variable = column = expression  
  | column_name { += | -= | *= | /= | %= | &= | ^= | |= } expression  
  | @variable { += | -= | *= | /= | %= | &= | ^= | |= } expression  
  | @variable = column { += | -= | *= | /= | %= | &= | ^= | |= } expression  
  } [ ,...n ]
```

As you can see, the only options in `<set clause>` are individual columns/assignments. There is no "bulk" assignment option. Lower down in the documentation you'll find the options for `INSERT` also requires individual expressions (at least, in the `VALUES` clause - you can omit the column names after the `INSERT` but that's generally frowned upon).

SQL tends to favour verbose, explicit syntax.

Comment: I was hoping there was something that went over my head there, but you're right, it must be explicit. Sadly, this means that I get less repetition if I break the INSERT and UDPATE statements apart: at least, I will only have to repeat the full column list twice (once in each) rather than three times (in the definition of Source).